# How to add settings menu in toolbar react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, toolbar, stack-navigator

I have used StackNavigator for naviagtion and toolbar, now i tried

```
<ToolbarAndroid
      logo={require('./app_logo.png')}
      title="AwesomeApp"
      actions={[{title: 'Settings', icon: require('./icon_settings.png'), show: 'always'}]}
      onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
```

but didn't got what i expected  
[image: settings menu on toolbar]

i need menu as above image.

Comment: What are you getting right now ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda showing stacknavigator items not settings options